# Why does Diep.io turn black while playing on Safari?

Tags: diep.io

I played Diep.io on Safari and after a few seconds of playing the game, the screen turned black. I tried again with Google Chrome, but the screen doesn't turn black at all.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diep.io is known to cause this issue on Safari. It is best to wait until the developer pushes a fix.